# Good tutorial + reference for Emacs search and replace?

Tags: emacs, reference, replace

For a new user of Emacs, are the any good tutorials + references for learning and getting familiar with Emacs's search, replace and regex features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Emacs, press <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> to go to the manual and look at the section on Searching and Replacement. That'll cover everything you need, I think.

Comment: The Search link under Important Text-Changing Commands also leads to the same place.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of good resources online for how to do this.  A cursory search uncovered:

[EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) and more specifically: [EmacsWiki Regular Expressions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).

A good Emacs tutorial can be found at: [A guided tour of Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/).

If you have specific examples that are not working as you expect, let's see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [A guided tour of Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/), since it contains a pretty good crash-course in search-replace a bit down. Look for the heading **Regular expression search and replacement** `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I've found this blogpost usefull: http://psung.blogspot.com/2009/12/subtleties-of-search-and-replace-in.html.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to search and replace in Emacs. The Emacs Wiki page on [CategorySearchAndReplace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySearchAndReplace) has a good summary of links to pages that cover different search and replace options, including:

1. Search in Buffers
2. Replace in Buffers
3. Search Across Files
4. Replace Across Files

Drill down from that page to the search/replace topics of interest.