# Highlighting lines in emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I am using an IM which does not support viewing previous chat history nor can I change my IM. So I have to copy the chat into a text file everytime.

I am using Emacs.Is there some way by which I can highlight the lines which contain the participant names as below?

```
===> **[Vivek Kumar]**  
Hi, how are you doing!  
===> **[Mr X Y Z]**    
fine  
===> **[Vivek Kumar]**  
sdfksd;fks;
```

**EDIT 1:**

Earlier when I'd access to *gvim*, I would use the `highlight.vim` plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emacs supports highlighting of lines or phrases. You can use one of `highlight-lines-matching-regexp`, `highlight-phrase`, or `highlight-regexp`. I'm sure there are several others too.

To try this, paste your text into the editor, press `ESC-x` (or `Alt-x` might work too) to enter the "mini-buffer" at the bottom of the editor window, and enter one of the above commands.

For example, I tried:
`highlight-lines-matching-regexp` and entered the regexp "`\[.*\]`" and made it match the names in your example. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Just after running highlight-lines-matching-regexp]

You can tweak this expression to fit your needs. Some links to regular expressions in emacs:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression
- This question on SO: [Good tutorial + reference for Emacs search and replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3681284/562139)

Of course you could also use `highlight-phrase` and just highlight a simple string of text (instead of messing with regexes).

Here's one where I ran `highlight-phrase` and entered the two separate names and gave them different colors (`hi-yellow` and `hi-red`):

[image: After running highlight-phrase]

Finally you can then run `unhighlight-regexp` to clear out the highlighting.

Comment: Amazing, you taught me something there!

Comment: @dearvivekkumar You're welcome :) I discovered this feature when I once had to scan a large text file and look for a single repeating string in it. Also, here's a nice way to discover feature in emacs: `ESC-x apropos` and enter a word such as `highlight` and it will tell you functions that have that word in it.

Comment: please add the `C-x w r` and `C-x w p` keyboard binding/shortcut to the answer

Comment: Hmm, the default emacs (22.1.1) in OS X Mountain Lion does not appear have those shortcuts defined.

Comment: `C-x w` only becomes available after you've used a highlighting command or enabled `global-hi-lock-mode` — a bit weird.

Comment: The more normal prefix binding is `M-s h`. e.g. type `M-s h C-h`. These are in the global keymap, and bound by default. I've not noticed the `C-x w` bindings before, but those are evidentially in the `hi-lock-mode` keymap, and hence not available unless that mode is enabled.

Comment: @scorpiodawg using apropos will be helpful in learning and mastering emacs. Thanks for this too!!